# Z index in javascript animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index

Having a bit of a problem with the z index of some divs in my javascript.

I've used a bit of code from Rob White animates boxes by expanding their margins. It works great apart from the unhover part of the script.

The [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bpt6/1/fiddle) shows what happens.

On hover the divs animate and expand and a class of `top` is added with a z-index of 9999999

On unhover they shrink again but "pop" behind the neighbouring squares instead of remaining on top. The `top` class is removed at unhover but this has no bearing on the animation.

It actually only seems to happen at the edges an the bottom right corner is the only one that looks natural. Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `.top` after it ends the animation like this

```
$(this).stop(true, true).animate({
                marginTop: "5px",
                marginBottom: "5px",
                marginLeft: "5px",
                marginRight: "5px"
               }, 800,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("top");
            });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bpt6/3/)

Comment: Have you tried hovering again without waiting animation to stop?

Comment: That's excellent Amit, thankyou. Can you explain exactly what that does differently - I'm still learning here..

Comment: a nice [BLOG](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-jquery-animate-function/) post about jQuery Anmiate

Comment: Excellent thanks! One peculiarity (unfortunately I am having to use IE8) is that in reanimating the margins back to 0px that blanks out my box of text and disables the js for all subsequent hovers. It's fine in Chrome and also fine if I use 1px.